# Finding an efficient algorithm to get a line

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Given n horizontal segments, where the range of each segment is x2 - x1, what algorithm should i apply to get a straight line that gets me the biggest **combined** range (every intersection with a segment adds the range of that segment), its like finding a line to drill with, to get the maximum amount of water (water representing segments with X2-X1 quantity)
I completed the brute force algorithm with a depressing **big O (n^4)**

Comment: can you explain your brute force?

Comment: @juvian i basically went through all possible lines taking X amount of points from each segment and linking it to other X amount of points for every other segment, inside the loop, i call a function that checks the intersections with the array of segments, if the line intersects with a segment[n] it accumulates the range and checks if it is higher than the current max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume there is no segment that starts on the end of another, if not will need to modify a bit the following:

- For each segment, create 2 tuples: (x1, index) and (x2, index)
- Sort the tuples by its first value
- Set best = 0
- Iterate tuples. If its the start point (index wasn't seen before), add its value (x2 - x1) to best. If its an end point, substracts its value to best.
- The answer to the problem will be the highest value best reached.

Complexity: O(n log n)

Comment: Wow, that’s a very cool way to solve it. And the complexity of that solution is much more acceptable, i had a small hunch that the best one would be logarithmic, but with n^2 not n^1. Thanks a lot ! Cheers

Comment: But the only problem is that if i have 2 lines at they same Y, it will ignore the second line

Comment: @Marcel.af for repeating positions, you only have to make sure that when you sort, all start tuples come before end tuples (if same position). So given (10, 100), (100, 200) points, you need to sort the tuples as (10, 0), (100, 1), (100, 0), (200, 1). Can be easily done extending the tuple as (x, isStart, index) and using standard library sorting

Comment: that solves it, thank you very much for your time :)